# Mysql count rows of distinct values of price between range from give ids and return sum of count values

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two tables one is product and next is price table

Product Table

```
Id  Name
1   Bike
2   Car
3   Van
```

Price Table

```
Id Price   Pid
1   100    1
2   150    1
3   200    1
4   100    2
5   110    2
6   120    2
7   300    3
8   310    3
```

My Sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN price >= 0 AND price <= 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `0-2`,
SUM(CASE WHEN price >= 201 AND price <= 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `2-5`,
COUNT(pid) AS `All Values`
FROM price where pid IN(1,2,3)";
```

when I run this query price count values showing like below

0-2 has (6) count
2-5 has (2) count

but here I need to display as like.
here I am looking to display as two products between 0-200 matched that are 1,2 pids and so on
0-2 (2) count
2-5 (1) count

because in price table there are more price options there for products so every product has 2 to 5 different prices in the table but I should display it as one product count even more prices had.

Kindly tell me how to write mysql query.

I would appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ..)` and in `THEN` clause use `pid` instead of 1

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN price >= 0 AND price <= 200 THEN pid END) AS `0-2`,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN price >= 201 AND price <= 500 THEN pid END) AS `2-5`,
COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS `All Values`
FROM price 
WHERE pid IN(1,2,3)
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741a5d/5)